# In search of automatic drawing finite state machine graphs

Tags: graphs, automation

I am looking for some layouts or methods with which I could draw `Finite State Machine` graph. I have tried a lot of Tikz library layouts like: `spring`, `necklace`, `electrical` and so on.

Main thing what I am searching is that I could just put the names of states and it randomly drops my states in the paper and connect them with various connections without crossing in the middle of state and so on. I can't put any direction like bend left and so on.

I am searching this for my `C#`-code. My idea is to append my states names to LaTeX and then connect them with other states, by appending to LaTeX symbol like `->`. So I need to get the most automatically method or layout of FSM.

Is this at all possible? Or maybe you have something to offer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly you want Graphviz?  See fsm in the gallery: http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php.

Comment: you can use `JFLAP` to generate the FSM and transform the graph with `jflap2tikz`-package to LaTeX code

Comment: Related [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20784/which-package-can-be-used-to-draw-automata)

Comment: @MWc it is not related at all. I am asking about graph drawing without any hard coding of states and nodes positions in the paper.

Comment: @JimHefferon It is really nice idea, I will try it now :)

Comment: @Mantas - Sorry, I had misunderstood your question.